# Empty values in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to insert dataframe to cassandra:

```
result.rdd.saveToCassandra(keyspaceName, tableName)
```

However some of the column values are empty and thus I get exceptions:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toFloat(StringLike.scala:231)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toFloat(StringOps.scala:31)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$FloatConverter$$anonfun$convertPF$4.applyOrElse(TypeConverter.scala:216)
```

Is there a way to replace all EMPTY values with null in the dataframe and would that solve this issue?
For this question, lets assume this is the dataframe df:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
"A"  | "B"  | 1
"E"  | "F"  | 
"S"  | "K"  | 5
```

How can I replace that empty value in col3 with null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You cast the DataFrame column to your numeric type then any values that cannot be pared to the appropriate type will be turned into nulls.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
df.select(
   $"col1",
   $"col2",
   $"col3" cast IntegerType
)
```

or if you don't have a select statement

```
 df.withColumn("col3", df("col3") cast IntegerType)
```

If you have many columns that you want to apply this to and feel it would do too inconvenient to do this in a select statement or if casting wont work for your case, you can convert to rdd to apply the transformation then go back to a dataframe. You may want to define a method for this.

```
  def emptyToNull(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val sqlCtx = df.sqlContext
    val schema = df.schema

    val rdd = df.rdd.map(
      row =>
        row.toSeq.map {
          case "" => null
          case otherwise => otherwise
        })
      .map(Row.fromSeq)

    sqlCtx.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
  }
```

Comment: thanks, that transformation was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `udf` for this:

```
val df = Seq(("A", "B", "1"), ("E", "F", ""), ("S", "K", "1")).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
// make a udf that converts String to option[String]
val nullif = udf((s: String) => if(s == "") None else Some(s))

df.withColumn("col3", nullif($"col3")).show

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   B|   1|
|   E|   F|null|
|   S|   K|   1|
+----+----+----+
```

---

You can also use `when.otherwise`, if you want to avoid the usage of *udf*:

```
df.withColumn("col3", when($"col3" === "", null).otherwise($"col3")).show

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   B|   1|
|   E|   F|null|
|   S|   K|   1|
+----+----+----+
```

---

Or you can use SQL `nullif` function to convert empty string to null:

```
df.selectExpr("col1", "col2", "nullif(col3, \"\") as col3").show
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   B|   1|
|   E|   F|null|
|   S|   K|   1|   
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution other than UDFs, like some kinda dataframe transformation such as .map(...)

Comment: Updated two other methods for converting empty string to null.

Comment: your `when` example could be simplified to `when($"col3" !== "" $col3")` .  `when` will default to null when there is no `otherwise` clause.

Answer (score 0):

before use：

```
//将RDD映射到rowRDD
val rowRDD = personRDD.map(p => Row(p(0).trim.toLong, p(1).trim, p(2).trim, p(3).trim.toLong, p(4).trim.toLong))
```

use cast：

```
//通过StructType直接指定每个字段的schema
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("id", LongType, false) ::
    StructField("name", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("gender", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("salary", LongType, true) ::
    StructField("expense", LongType, true) :: Nil
)

//允许字段为空
val rdd = personRDD.map(row =>
  row.toSeq.map(r => {
    if (r.trim.length > 0) {
      val castValue = Util.castTo(r.trim, schema.fields(row.toSeq.indexOf(r)).dataType)
      castValue
    }
    else null
  })).map(Row.fromSeq)
```

Util method:

```
 def castTo(value: String, dataType: DataType) = {
dataType match {
  case _: IntegerType => value.toInt
  case _: LongType => value.toLong
  case _: StringType => value
}
```